# communicate scope values between controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

1. using getters and setters in services, later calling the service and fetching values
2. $Broadcast and $emit

Which is best practice and why ?

Comment: Overly using $rootscope.$broadcast and $rootscope.$emit pollutes $rootscope

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is for entire application then choose $broadcost and $emit,
if it is just between two or three controllers or views better go for services,factories,$rootScopes

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you store data in a service when `Controller1` is in scope.
Then you navigate to a different page, means `Controller1` goes out of scope and new `Controller2` comes into scope. If you want to access previously stored data in `Controller2`, you can easily fetch by calling the service.

If you use `$broadcast` and `$emit` then only way to share data between `Controller1` and `Controller2` is if you register `$broadcast`, `$emit` events on `$rootScope`. If you add too much stuff to `$rootscope` then you are polluting it which is not a good thing. But, if you are using it for very limited amount of times, then probably its fine.

This may also help
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

If you just want to store data access across application, you can also cache data
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

```
angular.module('superCache')
  .factory('superCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('super-cache');
}]);
angular.module("module1", [])
.controller("controller1", function(superCache){
 superCache.put('key', 'value');
 superCache.put('another key', {});
})
 angular.module("module2", [])
.controller("controller2", function(superCache){
 $scope.data1 =  superCache.get('key');
 $scope.obj1 = superCache.put('another key');
})
```

Comment: Using emit and broadcast will increase the lines of code, whereas service once defined with get and set can be used anywhere right ?

Comment: Its not about increasing lines of code if you use emit and broadcast. You should try to avoid registering emit and broadcast events on $rootscope. Yes, service can act a centralized place to hold data.